# Screen resolution and multiple users

Tags: windows-xp, resolution

Is it possible to have different screen resolution for different users logged at the moment into the system?
When I switch user and change screen resolution windows changes resolution for all the other  users also.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Maybe there is a better way for this.

Comment: I want to test how my app looks like in different resolutions but don't want to rearrange icons on desktop after every resolution change.

Comment: what about using vms?

Comment: vm what? (minimum comment is 15 symbols)

Comment: You could use a virtual machine like https://www.virtualbox.org/ to emulate different systems with different resolutions. With his way, you could test in different OS environments, too.

Comment: Yeah, or buy another PC, because Windows™ developers did not think that users might change screen resolution.

Comment: Why not vms? Virtual box is a free tool and as long as it is just for testing, you may install any windows system and use the unregistered 30 day trial.
By the way, the developers might have done this because they figured that no user would want another resolution that the native one of his monitor and every software should have a dynamic interface that can scale from at least 800x600 to NxN.

Comment: +1 to Ask. I thought this was a great question because it isn't that uncommon for multiple people sharing the same computer to prefer different resolutions, even if it does mean running the monitor at a non-native resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the tool [Carroll](http://thesz.diecru.eu/content/carroll.php):

[image]

> You can set for every user a different screen resolution. After logon
>   the screen resolution will be changed to the stored setting.
>
> **At the first time, the application shows all available screen
>   resolution. Select the desired screen resolution and click ‘Change
>   screen resolution and restore with every logon’. Next time, Carroll
>   changes the screen resolution automatically without displaying the
>   user interface.**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect solution, but it's close to what you're asking for.  Set up a single user as the test user so the desktop icons on your main user account don't get messed up, then use a resolution-switching utility such as [Display Changer](http://download.cnet.com/Display-Changer/3000-2072_4-10912673.html) to change resolutions.  You could simply create a separate Windows shortcut for each resolution, or create a set of batch files that automatically run Display Changer with different arguments before running your app.